# Finding the LFSR and connection polynomial for binary sequence.

Tags: stream-cipher, finite-field

I have written a C implementation of the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~mironov/cs359/massey.pdf) to work on finite fields of size any prime. It works on most input, except for the following binary GF(2) sequence:

$0110010101101$ producing LFSR $\langle{}7, 1 + x^3 + x^4 + x^6\rangle{}$

i.e. coefficients $c_1 = 0, c_2 = 0, c_3 = 1, c_4 = 1, c_5 = 0, c_6 = 1, c_7 = 0$

However, when using the recurrence relation

\begin{equation}
s_j = (c_1s_{j-1} + c_2s_{j-2} + \cdots + c_Ls_{j-L}) \mbox{ for } j \geq L.
\end{equation}
to check the result, I get back:

0110010001111, which is obviously not right.

Using the [Berlekamp-Massey Algorithm calculator](http://berlekamp-massey.appspot.com/) they say the (I believe) characteristic polynomial should be $x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x^1$. Which, according to my paper working, the reciprocal should indeed be $1 + x^3 + x^4 + x^6$.

What am I doing wrong?  Where is my understanding lacking?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134545/14578) on Math.SE.  Please don't cross-post.  That fragments answers and violates site rules.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was cross-posted and was better off on the other site anyways.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably just a difference in notation than any failure in
understanding or implementation. Some people define recurrence relations with subscripts in reverse order than others; the original description given by Berlekamp in his 1968 book *Algebraic Coding
Theory* began counting from $1$ instead of $0$ etc.  Observe that
$$x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x^1 = x^7(1 + x^{-3} + x^{-4} + x^{-6})$$
in comparison to your $1 + x^3 + x^4 + x^6$ which you say is the
correct reciprocal of what the web site's answer should be.
So I would say that the web site seems to be following
Berlekamp's original description and giving you an answer that is "off-by-one".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there was an implementation problem.

Quoting [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134545/finding-the-lfsr-and-connection-polynomial-for-binary-sequence):

> It seems to me that something went wrong, when you tried to regenerate the sequence. When the linear span is $7$ and the feedback polynomial is $1+x^3+x^4+x^6$, we have the recurrence relation
>   $$
> s_j=s_{j-3}+s_{j-4}+s_{j-6}
> $$
>   for all $j\ge 7$.
>
> Your sequence has $s_0=0$, $s_1=1$, $s_2=1$, $s_3=0$, $s_4=0$, $s_5=1$, $s_6=0$ as the initial segment. Using the above recurrence relation gives
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> s_7&=s_4+s_3+s_1=1,\\
> s_8&=s_5+s_4+s_2=0,\\
> s_9&=s_6+s_5+s_3=1,\\
> s_{10}&=s_7+s_6+s_4=1,\\
> s_{11}&=s_8+s_7+s_5=0,\\
> s_{12}&=s_9+s_8+s_6=1,
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   recovering the remaining of your input.

Comment: Hi jamesj629 and welcome to crypto. Please provide a short summary of the document you linked.